# how to correctly use remoteUser with vscode devContainer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to build a cross-compile dev environment and vscode's devcontainers look to be perfect for the job.

I have created an image with my toolchain in it, based off ubuntu:20.04.

Everything works almost perfectly with this `.devcontainer` file:

```
{
  "image": "my_image"
}
```

However the terminal runs with a root prompt when I `Open Folder In Container...`. I'd like it to run with my username.

So I made the `.devcontainer` file look like this:

```
{
  "image": "my_image"
  "mounts": [
    "type=bind,source=/etc/passwd,target=/etc/passwd,readonly=true",
    "type=bind,source=/etc/group,target=/etc/group,readonly=true"
  ],
  "remoteUser": "${env:USERNAME}"
}
```

which produces the following error message when attempting to `Open folder in container...`

```
[652 ms] unable to find user vorpalsword: no matching entries in passwd file
[652 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[652 ms] Stdin closed!
[653 ms] Error: An error occurred setting up the container.
[653 ms]     at Use (/home/vorpalsword/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.255.4/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1868:1339)
[653 ms]     at jO (/home/vorpalsword/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.255.4/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1868:1275)
[653 ms]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[653 ms]     at async Xse (/home/vorpalsword/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.255.4/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1874:2030)
[653 ms]     at async Uf (/home/vorpalsword/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.255.4/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1874:3193)
[654 ms]     at async Cae (/home/vorpalsword/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.255.4/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1994:10350)
[654 ms]     at async yae (/home/vorpalsword/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.255.4/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:1994:10104)
```

here's my docker file:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#install python, needed for unpacking sdk.sh
RUN apt update &&\
  apt install -qq -y software-properties-common &&\
  add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa &&\
  apt update &&\
  apt install -qq -y python3.8

# install compiler and build tools
RUN apt update &&\
  apt install -qqy build-essential &&\
  apt install -qq -y cmake

# install git
RUN apt update &&\
  apt install -qq -y git

# install the toolchain
COPY sdk.sh .
RUN ./sdk.sh && rm sdk.sh



ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: update - although vscode fails to remote in to the remote container, it leaves it running. I exec'd into it and verified that the contents of its local /etc/passwd & /etc/group were indeed mounted from my local machine.